# VS Code debugger exits out when I hit play or run button

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging

I want to use debugger with node.

VS Code debugger exits out when I hit play or run button. It just exits out , it shows no breakpoint.

Here are my config:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "JS Program",
      "runtimeVersion": "20",
      "program": "${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using `nvm`. I have tried different configs nothing helps.

Comment: VSC stores info in a `.db` (sqlite3) file for each workspace (near the `keybindings.json` file) search the UUID folder of your workspace and see if the `.db` is really big, close VSC, rename the `.db` file and its backup and restart VSC, for some reason these files can get very big and VSC has difficulty starting a debugger, at least for me when developing extensions

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "program" to the entry point of your project.

Using the fully qualified path, or

${workspaceFolder}/fileNameHere.js

Good examples [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)